# Safety plan associated Hazards and precautions Sql query for BIRT report

Tags: relationship, birt, maximo

my  requirement is to have a list of  all Safety plan and their associated Hazards and precautions , there is no relation between SAFETYPLAN and HAZARD in database configuration. 
I need a Sql query for BIRT report,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select 
      sp.safetyplanid
      , sp.description
      , h.hazardid
      , h.description 
      , p.precautionid
      , P.description
      , p.siteid
  from 
      safetyplan sp
  join 
      spworkasset spwa 
      on sp.safetyplanid = spwa.safetyplanid
  join 
      splexiconlink spll
      on spwa.spworkassetid = spll.spworkassetid
  join 
      safetylexicon sl
      on spll.safetylexiconid = sl.safetylexiconid
  join 
      hazard h
      on sl.hazardid = h.hazardid
  left join 
      hazardprec hp
      on h.hazardid = hp.hazardid
  left join
      precaution p
      on hp.precautionid = p.precautionid  
      and hp.siteid = p.siteid  
 order by sp.safetyplanid, h.hazardid, p.precautionid
```

Answer (score 0):

well, in my 7.6 environment there are relations for the safetyplan object and things have something to do with hazards.

Hazards are stored in the SAFETYLEXICON object. Associated things like hazardous materials, precoutions and so on in SPLEXICONLINK.

A good way to start to get an idea how the information is related is to look at the application definition and the relation on the table that displays the information to the user.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply Jeroen. You are right that SAFETYLRXICON and SPLEXICONLINK are there. Even hazard and precautions has HAZARDPREC object for relation. But im unable to identify any link/relation or contraint between SAFETYPLAN and associated HAZARDs.